# Parallel class function calls using python joblib

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, joblib

It is possible to make multiple calls to a function in python using joblib.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed 

def normal(x):
    print "Normal", x
    return x**2

if  __name__ == '__main__':

    results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(normal)(x) for x in range(20))
    print results
```

Gives: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]`

However, what I really want is to call a class function on a list of class instances in parallel. The function simply stores a class variable. Then later I will access this variable.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed 

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def p(self):
        self.y = self.x**2

if  __name__ == '__main__':

    runs = [A(x) for x in range(20)]
    Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(run.p() for run in runs))
    for run in runs:
        print run.y
```

This gives an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('G:/My Drive/CODE/stackoverflow/parallel_classfunc/parallel_classfunc.py',
>   wdir='G:/My Drive/CODE/stackoverflow/parallel_classfunc')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 86, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "G:/My
>   Drive/CODE/stackoverflow/parallel_classfunc/parallel_classfunc.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(run.p() for run in runs))
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line
>   183, in delayed
>       pickle.dumps(function)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\copy_reg.py", line 70, in
>   _reduce_ex
>       raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.**name**
>
> TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

How is it possible to use joblib with classes like this? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***How*** is it possible to use **`joblib`** with classes like this ?

Let's propose some code polishing first :

Not all things will fit the `joblib.Parallel()( delayed() )` call-signature capabilities to swallow:

```
# >>> type( runs )                        <type 'list'>
# >>> type( runs[0] )                     <class '__main__.A'>
# >>> type( run.p() for run in runs )     <type 'generator'>
```

so, let's make the DEMO-objects to pass "through" **`aContainerFUN()`**:

**`StackOverflow_DEMO_joblib.Parallel.py` :**

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time

class A( object ):

    def __init__( self, x ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = "Defined on .__init__()"

    def p(        self ):
        self.y = self.x**2

def aNormalFUN( aValueOfX ):
    time.sleep( float( aValueOfX ) / 10. )
    print ": aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == {0:} to process.".format( aValueOfX )
    return aValueOfX * aValueOfX

def aContainerFUN( aPayloadOBJECT ):
    time.sleep( float( aPayloadOBJECT.x ) / 10. )
    # try: except: finally:
    pass;  aPayloadOBJECT.p()
    print  "| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id({0:}) to process. [ Has made .y == {1:}, given .x == {2: } ]".format( id( aPayloadOBJECT ), aPayloadOBJECT.y, aPayloadOBJECT.x )
    time.sleep( 1 )

if __name__ == '__main__':
     # ------------------------------------------------------------------
     results = Parallel( n_jobs = 2
                         )(       delayed( aNormalFUN )( aParameterX )
                         for                             aParameterX in range( 11, 21 )
                         )
     print results
     print '.'
     # ------------------------------------------------------------------
     pass;       runs = [ A( x ) for x in range( 11, 21 ) ]
     # >>> type( runs )                        <type 'list'>
     # >>> type( runs[0] )                     <class '__main__.A'>
     # >>> type( run.p() for run in runs )     <type 'generator'>

     Parallel( verbose = 10,
               n_jobs  = 2
               )(        delayed( aContainerFUN )( run )
               for                                 run in runs
               )
```

---

### Results ? Works as charm !

> ```
> C:\Python27.anaconda> python StackOverflow_DEMO_joblib.Parallel.py
> ```

```
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 11 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 12 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 13 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 14 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 15 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 16 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 17 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 18 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 19 to process.
: aNormalFUN() has got aValueOfX == 20 to process.
[121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400]
.
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(50369168) to process. [ Has made .y == 121, given .x ==  11 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(50369168) to process. [ Has made .y == 144, given .x ==  12 ]
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    2.4s
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12896752) to process. [ Has made .y == 169, given .x ==  13 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12896752) to process. [ Has made .y == 196, given .x ==  14 ]
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    4.9s
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12856464) to process. [ Has made .y == 225, given .x ==  15 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12856464) to process. [ Has made .y == 256, given .x ==  16 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(50368592) to process. [ Has made .y == 289, given .x ==  17 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(50368592) to process. [ Has made .y == 324, given .x ==  18 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12856528) to process. [ Has made .y == 361, given .x ==  19 ]
| aContainerFUN: has got aPayloadOBJECT.id(12856528) to process. [ Has made .y == 400, given .x ==  20 ]
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:   13.3s finished
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work for me.You're saying generate the list of runs first then pass them through a normal function, which calls the class function.

```class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = "Defined on .__init__()"
    def p(self): 
        self.y = self.x**2
        print "Worked", self.x, self.y
def worker(r): 
    r.p() 
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    runs = [A(x) for x in range(20)]
    Parallel(n_jobs=2)( delayed(worker)(run) for run in runs )```

Comment: Sure, **the answer demonstrated a fully working code**, with a repaired syntax for the calls inside the `Parallel(...)( delayed(...)...)`. The call of the **class-method `.p()`** has been demo-ed as being deferred into the respective `Parallel`-factory instantiated new processes. **This is how the `joblib` works**, when using it's `multiprocessing` back-end engine. **Your post** did not meet the call-signature syntax ( ref. Traceback details above ), which **was repaired with a fully functional code** as was demonstrated above and remains here being available for a repeatable re-inspection(s).

Comment: AHA! Yes I followed your syntax and reproduced your code behaviour. The last thing was to update the list of class instances ("runs") correctly! 

`aContainerFUN` must `return aPayloadOBJECT`

so that we can do

`runs = Parallel(verbose=10, n_jobs=2)( delayed(worker)(run) for run in runs )`. Then we are able to access `runs[0].y` as desired in my question.

Comment: Sure, the next step is to measure the actual real-world costs of entering the parallel-paths. The net-efficiency ( expressed as the net real **benefit** / the total of all **costs**, including all add-on overhead costs - here pickle/unpickle SER/DES passes + multiprocessing governed process-management costs ) **decides**. Feel free to read more details about ***hidden* overheads** and **if** any speedups were actually achieved ( if and only if > 1.0) in **this article >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3**. The core question  to be benchmarked + answered **before** refactoring

Answer (score 1):

Let the first tweak class a/c to the first function:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def p(self):
        self.y = self.x**2
        return self.y
```

Now to run the above class parallelly, just use a lambda function instead of calling it directly(run.p()).

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed 

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def p(self):
        self.y = self.x**2
        return self.y

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    runs = [A(x) for x in range(20)]
    with Parallel(n_jobs=6, verbose=5) as parallel:
        delayed_funcs = [delayed(lambda x:x.p())(run) for run in runs]
        run_A = parallel(delayed_funcs)

    print(run_A)
```

Your output looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done   6 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  14 out of  20 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  20 out of  20 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
```